# How to trigger a Spring cloud task from an external application?

Tags: spring-cloud-task

I have created a spring cloud task that will perform some specific task based on the requirement. I wanted to call this task from another spring boot application. Please let me know is there any way of calling the below task from an external application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
public class FileGenerationTaskApplication {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public class FileGeneratorTaskConfigurer extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {
        public FileGeneratorTaskConfigurer(DataSource dataSource){
            super(dataSource);
        }
    }

    @Bean()
    public FileGeneratorTaskConfigurer getTaskConfigurer() {
        return new FileGeneratorTaskConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileGenerationTaskApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Component
    public static class FileGeneratorTaskRunner implements  ApplicationRunner {

        @Autowired
        private FulfillmentFileGenerationService service;


        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("FileGeneratorTaskRunner from Spring Cloud Task!");
            service.fulFillmentFileGenerationTask();
        }
    }

}
```

Can we create a REST api to call the spring cloud task?

Comment: You can create a stream with task-launcher sink to launch a Task in PCF, and then make a custom trigger to invoke the stream. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-mesos/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-launch-tasks-from-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have the `Task` registered on [Spring Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/). 
After you have your Task registered, you can make REST calls to trigger the Task. Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521684/3983547) out.

You can also use [Spring Cloud Dataflow Rest Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client)

```
DataFlowOperations dataFlowOperations = new DataFlowTemplate(URI.create(springDataFlowUri));
TaskOperations operations = dataFlowOperations.taskOperations();
```

Then you can start launching the Tasks previously got using the API Rest.

In case you do not want to use Spring Cloud DataFlow, remember when you create a Task, this is a Spring Boot Application by itself, so you can [expose end points](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to trigger the Task.

Comment: Thank you for giving me some inputs. Is it possible to trigger a spring cloud task without using Spring Cloud DataFlow?

Comment: @Ravikiran you can expose end points given that Spring Task is a Spring Boot Application. Please see the update to the answer.

Comment: @Ravikiran Please provide any feedback in case this answer is not enough.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using the task launcher and spring cloud stream